# timer doesn't work in qStudio

Tags: kdb

Consider the easiest timer example:

```
.z.ts: {[] show .z.T}
\t 500
```

This works fine in `cmd prompt` but I can't get it to work in qStudio's console. Why is this?

It outputs:

```
    q).z.ts: {[] show .z.T}
::
    q)\t 500
::
```

Comment: `show` will output in the process log, not in qStudio. Also, I'm not sure if qStudio interprets this as 2 lines rather than  1 when you don't have a semi colon. (assuming you highlight and execute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. Show displays the value in the kdb console.
2. There's an issue with how kdb handles remote calls involving slashes. As detailed here: http://www.timestored.com/qstudio/help/faq
   You should replace `\t 500` with `system "t 500";` and the timer will now be set.

Comment: It still doesn't work when I do: `.z.ts: {[] show .z.T}; system "t 500";` ? It still doesn't show in the console.

Comment: The "console" in qStudio only gives a console-like view of how any returned data looks. It does not show what is displayed at the actual kdb console. As kdb processes can run on remote machines, there's no reliable way to capture their actual terminal output.